# Library will only load with LD_PRELOAD

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, shared-libraries, shared-objects

**OS:** Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit

**Python:** 2.7.12

I have a really simple Python program which is just loading two libraries `libhidapi-hidraw` and `libpcProxAPI`. The latter is dependent on the former.

```
from ctypes import *

hidapi = CDLL('/home/wsharp/Source/pyprox/libhidapi-hidraw.so')
pcProxAPI = CDLL('/home/wsharp/Source/pyprox/libpcProxAPI.so')

r = pcProxAPI.usbConnect()
```

If I run `>python myfile.py` I receive the following error: *"undefined symbol: hid_send_feature_report"*

However if I run `>LD_PRELOAD=./libhidapi-hidraw.so python myfile.py` I don't receive any issues.

I've tried placing the `libhidapi-hidraw.so` in `/usr/lib` and other paths sourced by `ldconfig` with no luck. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but it's driving me nuts. Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

Including the output of `sudo ldconfig -v 2>/dev/null | grep -v ^$'\t'`

```
sudo ldconfig -v 2>/dev/null | grep -v ^$'\t'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfakeroot:
/lib/i386-linux-gnu:
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu:
/usr/local/lib:
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa-egl:
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa:
/lib:
/usr/lib:
```

**EDIT 2**

```
ldd libpcProxAPI.so
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff9d3b9000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f276c231000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f276bf28000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f276bd11000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f276b948000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000055dfcf780000)
```

Comment: What if you say `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. python myfile.py`?  Does that work?

Comment: @JohnZwinck tried that command, no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confirm if you are placing the file in one of the paths searched by linker:

```
ldconfig -v 2>/dev/null | grep -v ^$'\t'
```

If it is not, you have few options:

1. Set LD_LIBRARY_PATH to the directory containing the .so files
2. Add the directory to /etc/ld.so.conf and run ldconfig - (need root)

Comment: Output of that command in the original post. I've placed the *.so file in `/usr/lib` and `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`. Still no luck.

Comment: If you run ldd on libProxy.., does it show the dependency correctly? If not did you compile it? You have to link the dependencies for it to automatically pick up

Comment: If you cant recompile, ldpreload is indeed a workaround

Comment: I ran `ldd` on the library; output in the original post. I don't see `hidapi-hidraw` in the ouput. This is a shared object compiled by a vendor, so unfortunately I don't have the source code. Is this something I should contact the vendor about?

Comment: Yes, it has to be correctly linked against the dependency. Otherwise, I imagine you'd have to use ldpreload I fear.

Comment: Alright, thank you very much. This is all quite new to me. One follow up question: why doesn't explicitly loading the required library `hidapi-hidraw` have the same outcome as `LD_PRELOAD`?

Comment: With ldpreload you are essentially bypassing the linker and hence it will be loaded. I am on phone currently but you can potentially dlload from python instead of cdll to load the dependency